# How to Copy Outer HTML Using jQuery or Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using First part of following solution I am able to copy value of the input into clipboard. but can you please let me know how about copying HTML like a entire `<p>`? As you can see I am getting

> copyHTML.select is not a function

can you please let me know if this is doable in JS and how I can fix this?

```js
$("#copy").on("click", function(){
      var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
});


$("#copyHTML").on("click", function(){
      var copyHTML = document.getElementById("sample");
  copyHTML.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyHTML.HTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button id="copy">Copy text</button>


<p id="sample" class="napper">This is atest Paragraph</p>
<button id="copyHTML">Copy HTML</button>
```

Comment: So...you're looking for the DOM element `.outerHTML` property?

Comment: yes something like clone but copying to clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the HTML element.

```
$("#copyHTML").on("click", function(){
      var copyHTML = document.getElementById("sample");
  copyHTML.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the HTML (notice the .outerHTML): " + copyHTML.outerHTML);
});
```

Comment: But I need to copy it to clipboard

Comment: @JJBOBO just updated the answer :) let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

My favorite approach (no jquery):

```
addEventListener("focus", (event) => 
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(document.body.innerHTML)
  .then(()=>console.log("string copied to clipboard")) );
```